# Meaning of "to be due for a set"

Tags: meaning

> Dr Li: Okay, I'll take a look. It looks a little discolored. We'll get a set of X-rays today to get to the bottom of it.
>
> Tina: X-rays? Will that be an out-of-pocket expense?
>
> Dr Li: No, **you're due for a set**. It'll be covered by your insurance.

If you break it down what does "due"& "a set" mean and also overall meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*disclaimer: not medical advice.*

He probably means that you can get a number of x-ray prints (a *set* of them) made for free.

> **due** *adjective*
>   1.2 (of a person) having reached a point where the thing mentioned is required or owed.
>   ‘she was due for a rise’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/due)

Comment: I've added a definition and edited your answer for clarity and formatting. Please feel free to [edit] further or to roll back the changes.

Comment: I would agree. As he is talking about discolouration it sounds as though Dr Li is a dentist and Tina is a patient with an insurance plan. My limited experience of dental plans is that periodic X-rays are part of the plan and when they are _due_ the insurance company will pay for enough X-ray shots to give a complete view of the state of Tina's teeth. These X-ray shots form a _set_ of X-rays. What Dr Li is saying that enough time has passed since Tina's last set of X-rays that the insurance company will pay for another set.

Comment: Thank you all for good responses >> BoldBen & Lawrence & ODO